# how to create some space between two angular js elements?

Tags: html, angularjs

here is my angular js markup:

```
        <div layout="row">
        <h1 ui-sref="home" style="cursor:pointer">Element A</h1>
        <h1 flex="10"></h1>
        <h1 ui-sref="simulator" style="cursor:pointer">Element B</h1>
        </div>
```

however in the browser I see "Element A" and "Element B" very close to each other.

How can i make some space between them?

Comment: You can add a breakline with <br>

Comment: Did you try adding &nbsp; and height in that h1 flex 10?

Answer (score 1):

**CSS is your friend.** Simply apply either margin or padding to space out your html elements like h1's. This is what CSS is for - it is better to apply styling rather than rely on html elements like a 
 to space things apart.

```
h1 {margin: 15px;}
```

Also - you should perhaps not have multiple h1's - semantically there should only be one h1 per semantic section (it used to be stated that you should only have 1 h1 per page - but with the advent of self contained HTML5 elements like sections - each one may have a h1 -h6) although I personally prefer to only have 1 h1 and treat all other headings as subservient to that.

also better to not have your styles inline - but in the hea or in an external style sheet.

```css
h1{
  margin: 15px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div layout="row">
   <h1 ui-sref="home" >Element A</h1>
   <h1 flex="10"></h1>
   <h1 ui-sref="simulator">Element B</h1>
 </div>
```